# VBA How to make a msgbox to repeat only once for certain values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print only a part of the msgbox after all cells are iterated. So I need only one repetition- for all found cells only once. This is the whole message box:

[image]

I  want to print only this part of the message box:

[image]

This is the code:

```
Sub checkcolumns()

Dim rngCheck As Range
Dim cell As Range, j As String, mess As String
Dim TextBlockCanBeDefined, noTextBlockCanBeDefined As String

   Set rngCheck = Range("B3:B6")

For Each cell In rngCheck
If IsEmpty(cell) Then

    j = j & cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine
    If cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "L" Then
        TextBlockCanBeDefined = TextBlockCanBeDefined & j & vbNewLine

    ElseIf cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "T" Then
        noTextBlockCanBeDefined = noTextBlockCanBeDefined & j & vbNewLine

    End If

End If
Next cell


mess = vbCrLf & "For the line paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine &   TextBlockCanBeDefined & "no “Text Block Row” can be defined"
mess = mess & vbCrLf & "For the table paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & noTextBlockCanBeDefined & "is no “Text Block Row” defined"
 If mess <> "" Then MsgBox mess


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
For Each cell In rngcheck
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        ***j = cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine***
        If cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "L" Then
            TextBlockCanBeDefined = TextBlockCanBeDefined & j & vbNewLine
            'For the table paragraph in row 7 is no “Text Block Row” defined
            'rngcheck.ClearContents
        ElseIf cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "T" Then
            noTextBlockCanBeDefined = noTextBlockCanBeDefined & j & vbNewLine
            'cell.Clear
        End If
        'mess = mess & vbCrLf & j & "is ok"
    End If
Next cell

mess = vbCrLf & "For the line paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & TextBlockCanBeDefined & "no “Text Block Row” can be defined"
mess = mess & vbCrLf & "For the table paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & noTextBlockCanBeDefined & "is no “Text Block Row” defined"
```

Comment: It`s posted now.

Comment: you deleted the following part: If mess <> "" Then MsgBox mess. this part is neccassary.

Comment: Now it works but the msg box: "For the line paragraph in row:" & vbNewLine & TextBlockCanBeDefined & "no “Text Block Row” can be defined" is repeated twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173201/discussion-between-denyo-and-hris).

Comment: hi, maybe ive got a solution: please edit following line: j = j & cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine to j = cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine